# Want to find any reference in any file to a certain string in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to search All .PHP files or ALL .SH files for any reference that contains:

'into tbl_free_minutes_mar'

I have command line access to the server but the files may be scattered in different directories.

Answer (score 2):

For all directories everywhere,

```
find / -type f \( -name '*.php' -o -name '*.sh' \) \
  -exec fgrep 'into tbl_free_minutes_mar' {} \+
```

For fewer directories elsewhere, just give a list of paths instead of `/`.  To just list the matching files, try `fgrep -l`.  If your file names might not always match the wildcards in the `-name` conditions, maybe scan all files.

Answer (score 0):

`find / -type f \( -name \*.php -o -name \*.sh \) -exec grep 'into tbl_free_minutes_mar' {} /dev/null \;`

Change `find / ...` to to something less all-encompassing if you know the general area that you want to look in, e.g. `find /home ...`

Answer (score 0):

Provided `/base/path` is the path where you want to start looking this will get you a list of files:

```
find /base/path -type f -iregex '.*\.\(php\|sh\)$' -exec grep -l 'into tbl_free_minutes_mar' '{}' \;
```